# Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am facing an issue with my google maps code. I am trying to place markers on my map from an array. But I am stuck in between when I am trying to do the same.My firebug console gives me an error that results is not defined in function createMarkers. Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var addresses = new Array();
abc = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
//loc = mydiv.getAttribute("data-addr");
var l = abc.length; 
 for (var i=0; i < l; i++){
    if (abc[i].hasAttribute('name'))
    {   
        addresses.push("'"+abc[i].innerHTML+"'");
    }   
}
var len = addresses.length;
var geocoder;
var map;
var add = document.getElementById("addr").value;
window.onload = function init() {

      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();    
      var add = document.getElementById("address").value;
      var latlng = codeAddress(add);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          myOptions);
}

//for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++)
//{
    function codeAddress(add) 
    {
      //var addr = addresses[i];
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address':add }, function(results, status) {

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);     
          } else {
              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
    }

    function createMarkers()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            (function(addresses){
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresses }, function(results) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,//error:results[0] is undefined
                        title: address
                    }); 

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        alert(addresses);
                    });
                });
            })(addresses[i]);
        }
    }
    window.onload = createMarkers;
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(results)` to see what it actually contains?

Comment: @winterblood Ya I tried. Its giving "results is not defined"

Comment: Have you also checked to make sure `address` has a value in your inner function?

Comment: @winterblood Ya srry actually `addresses` should be passed in function instead of `address` as addresses is my array which contains the addresses whose markers are to be created on map. I have edited the code but still the problem prevails.

Comment: Check this [google page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding). You did not initialized you map properly. Call to `new google.maps.LatLng(...)` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Well after a long battle with the code,I found the solution. The error I was facing because I was pushing the addresses into array in a wrong format i.e. I pushed the addresses into the array with a `'(single quote)` surrounding it,which the geocoder did not accept.So then finally edited the loc where I was pushing the address.The modified code is as :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var addresses = new Array();
abc = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
//loc = mydiv.getAttribute("data-addr");
var l = abc.length; 
 for (var i=0; i < l; i++){
    if (abc[i].hasAttribute('name'))
    {   
        addresses.push(""+abc[i].innerHTML+""); //removed single quotes here. see previous code
    }   
}
var len = addresses.length;
var geocoder;
var map;
var add = document.getElementById("addr").value;
window.onload = function init() {

      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();    
      var add = document.getElementById("address").value;
      var latlng = codeAddress(add);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          myOptions);
}

//for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++)
//{
    function codeAddress(add) 
    {
      //var addr = addresses[i];
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address':add }, function(results, status) {

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);     
          } else {
              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
    }

    function createMarkers()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            (function(addresses){
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresses }, function(results) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,//error:results[0] is undefined
                        title: address
                    }); 

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        alert(addresses);
                    });
                });
            })(addresses[i]);
        }
    }
    window.onload = createMarkers;
</script>
```

Comment: It [works for me with those single quotes](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_geocodeAddressesFromTable.html)

Comment: @geocodezip Ok.May be but it didnt work for me.It only worked when I removed those `single quotes`. Problem is that address will be geocoded but `createMarkers` function would create problem.